# Display custom task pane when appointment item is opened (meeting occurrence & individual meeting)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have some text embedded in the meeting invites sent by me. I want to launch a custom task pane when user opens the appointment from the calendar that contains text specified by me.

I am working with the InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler to get the open event and check if the appointment item is opened. In case of appointment i call the code to display custom task pane.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        if (appointmentItem != null)
        {
            (appointmentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event).Open += _appointment_Open;
            (appointmentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event).Close += ThisAddIn_Close;

        }

    }

private void _appointment_Open(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if ((Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonObj as Ribbon) != null && (Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonObj as Ribbon).IsLoggedOn)
        {
            Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            if (selObject is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem = (selObject as Outlook.AppointmentItem);
//Without display() the taskpane is displayed on the calendar screen
                apptItem.Display();
                //Dispose already open task panes
                (Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonObj as Ribbon).DisposeCustomTaskPanes();

                if (FindCustomId(apptItem.Body))
                {                        
                    (Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonObj as Ribbon).edit_Cick(null);
                }
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selObject);
        }
    }

edit_click()
{
CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane = 
Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "edit pane");
}
```

By using apptItem.Display();the appointment is opened and then the task pane is displayed with opened item only. If display() is not used then taskpane is opened in the calendar view of outlook not on the opened item.

The problem with this approach occurs when i am opening and recurrence item. If i open 'just this one' item then the scenario works fine. But if i open 'open entire series' then the open() event is fired twice and two windows are opened, one with meeting occurrence and other with meeting series. 'open series' will open only one window if i remove the display() method call.

*My goal is to avoid opening the custom task pane when user has opened a meeting series. The task pane will be displayed only if user opens a meeting occurrence or individual meeting.*
Also, is there a way to distinguish when appointment is opened as a meeting occurrence or meeting series. In open_event i get the Appointment.RecurrenceState as olApptOccurrence for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in new inspector i am distinguishing between master occurrence and occurrence item

```
Outlook.OlRecurrenceState rState = appointmentItem.RecurrenceState;
            if (rState == Outlook.OlRecurrenceState.olApptMaster)
                return;
            appointmentItem.Open += AppointmentItem_Open;
            (appointmentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event).Close += ThisAddIn_Close;
```

Then in the open event i am opening the custom task pane. With this i am able to achieve the desired result. Will update as answer once all test cases are passed.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `AppointmentItem.Open` event to show the task pane - use `NewInspector` event.

Comment: Thanks, i am able to distinguish between occurrence master and occurrence item. But the task pane is displayed on the calendar view only. As per documentation inspector event occurs after the new Inspector object is created but before the inspector window appears. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.newinspector.

Comment: Outlook.OlRecurrenceState rState = appointmentItem.RecurrenceState;
                if (rState == Outlook.OlRecurrenceState.olApptMaster)
                    return;             
                //Dispose already open task panes
                (Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonObj as Ribbon).DisposeCustomTaskPanes();
                if (FindCustomId(appointmentItem.Body))
                {                   
                    (Globals.ThisAddIn.ribbonObj as Ribbon).edit_Cick(null);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);

Comment: Yes, the inspector might not be visible at that moment, but why is it a problem?

Comment: the newly added custom task pane is not placed at the new inspector window.

Comment: Do you set myCustomTaskPane.Visibel to true? How do you create myUserControl?

Comment: MyUserControl uc= new MyUserControl ();
            Integration.ElementHost elementHost = new Integration.ElementHost();
            EditView elementView = new EditView();
            elementHost.Child = elementView;
            elementHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            uc.Width = 450;
            uc.Controls.Add(elementHost);
            CustomTaskPane myCTP = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(uc, customTaskPaneTitle);
            myCTP.Width = 450;
                        myCTP.Visible = true;

Comment: the problem is with position of taskpane. It is on calendar view, not on the opened appointment item (after double click on an appointment).

Comment: Do you mean it is on an Explorer rather than an Inspector? Then why do you even need NewInspector and AppointmentItem.Open events?

Comment: yes custmo task pane is on explorer. I want it to be on the inspector, The requirement is to open a taskpane on the newly opened appointment item when it is opened.

Comment: CustomTaskPanes.Add takes inspector as one of the parameters. See the sampel code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2019

Comment: Hi Dmitry, sorry for the delayed response. I am passing the inspector in in customtaskpane.Add. I can see the custom task pane for a fraction of seconds in the inspector window but it disappears automatically. I think i should go with appointment.Open event. I can't find any other way around this.

Comment: In addition to the above, i am displaying a loading window till i get the data required from web service call. I suppose this should not be any problem as custometaskpane.add call is made after the loading window is closed.